# xcode4.2 (storyboard, Navigation Controller) How to set custom Image for UINavigationBar

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, custom-controls, uinavigationbar, xcode4.2, storyboard

I`m creating the iPhone App by using the storyboard.
I have no idea how to set custom image for UINavigationBar.

Please teach me how to do that.
Well I`m not a programmer but just a designer.

#### Thank you so much giving me your nice code.

### I put the code to my "*MainAppDelegate.m*"

```
   - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    SelectClientNavController *controller = (SelectClientNavController *)navigationController.topViewController;
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourBackGroundImage.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    return YES;
}
```

#### But I got several errors like below!!

---

For this line:

```
SelectClientNavController *controller = (SelectClientNavController *)navigationController.topViewController;
```

*1. Expected expression*

*2. Use of undeclared identifier 'SelectClientNavController'*

*3. Use of undeclared identifier 'controller'*

---

For this line:

```
controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
```

*1. Property 'managedObjectContext' not found on object of type 'MainAppDelegeate*'*

*2. Use of undeclared identifier 'controller'*

---

### How can I fix above errors.

---

Answer (score 5):

I needed to do this also very soon so here it is: You can't do it in storyboard. The code best goes in your application delegate implementation file (AppDelegate.m). . Find the method "- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions" and change it to like like the following. You will only be adding one line of code.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController; // this line is probably already there for you
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourBackGroundImage.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault]; //this adds the image
    return YES;
}
```

Where "yourBackGroundImage.png" is your image. Make sure you have added the image to your project.

I believe this will work only for IOS 5.

Comment: Thank you so much giving me your nice code.
But I got several errors.

Comment: I put the errors above. If you can fix it, appreciate!! Thank you for advise.

Comment: @Monk see updated code. I believe the problem is that I left 2 lines of code in that are not applicable to your program. Essentially, you will just delete the two lines of code causing the errors.